# How to add dynamic radio buttons in custom checkout step?

Tags: magento, magento2, checkout

I have added a custom checkout step between shipping and billing step called Pickup step where customers can select the delivery datetime and select their preferred store for pickup which again will be based on the postcode selected by the user.
The problem here is that I can add the radio buttons via Layout Processor but that is visible with all steps so I want to add that in the HTML template but I don't have idea how do I get the data from the Knockout.js?
Checkout Custom Step:
[image: Checkout Custom Step]

Below is the code & files used

```
==========================================
checkout_index_index.xml
==========================================



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
         <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                              <item name="pickup-store-step" xsi:type="array">
                                 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                 <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                 <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="alldetails" xsi:type="array">
                                       <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module/js/view/pickup-store-step</item>
                                       <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                          <item name="pickup_details" xsi:type="array">
                                             <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                             <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                                             <item name="children" xsi:type="array" />
                                          </item>
                                          <item name="delivery_date" xsi:type="array">
                                             <item name="component" xsi:type="string">SR_DeliveryDate/js/view/delivery-date-block</item>
                                             <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                          </item>
                                       </item>
                                    </item>
                                 </item>
                              </item>
                           </item>
                        </item>
                     </item>
                  </item>
               </item>
            </argument>
         </arguments>
      </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>



==========================================
pickup-store-step.js
==========================================
define(
    [
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
    ],
    function (
        $,
        _,
        Component,
        ko,
        quote,
        stepNavigator,
        paymentService,
        methodConverter,
        getPaymentInformation,
        checkoutDataResolver,
        $t,
        customer
    ) {
        'use strict';
        /**
        * check-login - is the name of the component's .html template
        */
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Namespace_Module/pickup-store-step'
            },

            //add here your logic to display step,
            isVisible: ko.observable(quote.isVirtual()),
            quoteIsVirtual: quote.isVirtual(),
            isLogedIn: customer.isLoggedIn(),
            //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
            stepCode: 'pickup',
            //step title value
            stepTitle: 'Pickup Details',

            /**
            *
            * @returns {*}
            */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    this.stepCode,
                    null,
                    this.stepTitle,
                    this.isVisible,
                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                    15
                );

                return this;
            },

            navigate: function () {
                var self = this;

                getPaymentInformation().done(function () {
                    self.isVisible(true);
                });
            },

            /**
            * @returns void
            */
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);

==========================================
pickup-store-step.html
==========================================

<li data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible, attr: { id: stepCode }">
<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: stepTitle" data-role="title"></div>

    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">
        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">

            <label class="label">Delivery Date</label>
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="datetimepicker: true"  name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" readonly="true"/>
            </div>

            <label class="label">Comment</label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="delivery_comment" id="delivery_comment"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>


==========================================
LayoutProcessorPlugin.php
==========================================
public function afterProcess(
            \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
            array  $jsLayout
        ) {
            $postcode = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
            $args = array("postcode"=>$postcode);
            $stores = $this->findbakery->getNearByBakeryByCookie($args);
            $additionalOptions = [];
            $count = count($stores);
            $count = ($count > 5) ? 5 : $count ;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
            {
                if($i == 0)
                {
                    $additionalOptions[] = array(
                        'label' => $stores[$i]["store_name"],
                        'value' => $stores[$i]["gmapstrlocator_id"],
                        'checked' => "checked",
                    );
                }
                else
                {
                    $additionalOptions[] = array(
                        'label' => $stores[$i]["store_name"],
                        'value' => $stores[$i]["gmapstrlocator_id"],
                    );                    
                }
            }
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['pickup-store-step']['children']['pickup_store'] = [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/checkbox-set',
                    'config' => [
                        'template' => 'ui/form/element/checkbox-set',
                        'options' => $additionalOptions,
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'id' => 'pickup_store'
                    ],
                    'label' => 'Pickup Store',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'validation' => [],
                    'sortOrder' => 200,
                    'id' => 'pickup_store'
                ];

            return $jsLayout;
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I've added the custom checkout step which you can see here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1iOk.png But thats coming out of the step and also I can't save the data for this step, I want to add pickup store via knockout in the html template

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts, just added the code